# iphone web application

Tags: iphone

there is no need to wait for approval from Apple,in the case of hosting web applications in AppStore. Is that true?

Comment: The simple answer is if you're delivering your app through the App Store, you need approval from Apple. Otherwise, you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iPhone web application is the same as any other website (other than that it's optimized for mobile usage) so the user just visits your site via the browser. There is absolutely no approval process for web applications.

Comment: I think he may be referring to HTML/JS applications packaged as native apps, using tools like [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/).

Comment: In that case, the answer is still rather simple. Anything that is delivered through the App Store must be approved by Apple.

Comment: I am using uiwebview to display HTML/JS content for my application.